# What's a good practice for displaying extended output in a datatable?

Tags: data, popup

I have a datatable with various columns, including one that could potentially include 4k char output.  I currently set up the columns to display 200px worth of text.  If they want to see the rest of it, they just hover over it and a pop-up appears.

This works fine, except when users are close to the right-side or bottom of the window.  The pop-up extends from the cursor down and to the right, so the pop-up causes issues with scrollbars and such.

I could probably use some javascript and some math to figure out better places to display the output (if close to bottom right then, instead, pop-up window towards the top-left, etc)  But I'm also looking better ideas for displaying this kind of information.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to handle the situation. Based on your content and screen dimensions/resolutions appropriate solutions can be chosen.

Here is one: [Clipped Content](http://codepen.io/jvijaybhaskar/full/gaxMwN)
In this case, excess content in a cell is hidden and an ellipsis is shown allowing user to explore.

Here is another: [Converting excess columns to child row](http://codepen.io/jvijaybhaskar/full/ZbKOrj/)
In this case depending on the screen width and content, the right most columns care hidden and shown as child rows.

There are many more options like freezing a few columns and then allows the user to swipe through the remaining columns (like in excel).

> To sum it up, there is no right way of doing it! Asses the content and
>   the delivery mechanism, then choose the solution.